# Phone unlocks when call comes in

Tags: calls

I have a Samsung SM G930V, Android v 7.0

My phone is set to lock with the fingerprint scanner, but when a call comes in the phone automatically unlocks and when I pull it out of my pocket half the time I inadvertently hang up because I touch the hang up button as I am pulling it out of my pocket.

How do I make it stay locked even when a call comes in?
Meaning I want it to wait till I unlock before letting me answer or hang up.

Of course, if I am in the car with bluetooth I still want the answer button in the car to work without having to unlock it manually.

Comment: Are you saying that you want it to ask for your fingerprint before answering?

Comment: Yeah, a little unclear what the issue is.

Comment: Ask for fingerprint or correct swipe gesture. Am I really the only one with this problem?

Comment: Why don't you disable the setting for using volume/ power button for disconnecting call? Of course, you would have this behaviour persistent when when screen is unlocked

Comment: I am tapping the soft, red hangup button on the screen not the power button.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that unless you are using some other app for calls that doesn't shows *incoming call screen* while the phone is locked.
As *phone apps* are generally set with a  [`FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED) flag, which enables them to show incoming call while phone is locked.

Answer (score 1):

Always love it when I can add a non-technical answer. Thinking outside the box, you simply need a protective phone case from Ebay. For example I have this little beauty headed my way for my brand new Pixel 4A 5G with CalyxOS.
https://www.ebay.com/itm/353791237308
The case will prevent you from pressing any buttons inadvertently, and additionally it will extend the life of your screen. Problem solved.